# ITransformableFilterValues implementation to filter entries that contain the ParameterValues

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to create a custom filter Web Part. I found two ways of doing this: 1. implement `IFilterProvider` (but this is marked as obsolete) 2. implement `ITransformableFilterValues` (which seems to be the current way to do it, so I chose it).

Now I need to filter entires that are **not exact** matches of my `ParameterValues` but that **contain** my `ParameterValues`.

So can I use some kind of wildcard in `ParameterValues`? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your Filter Provider web part passes along filters (via either method) to a Filter Consumer it has no say on what the filter consumer actually does with these values.

The List View Web Part (LVWP) for example will NOT allow you to use wildcards.

Other web parts may do (but I am not aware of any).

Comment: So, if I want to filter using wildcards or using strings that only contain part of the target value, I can use the default Text Filter Web Part, but I have to build my own List View Web Part?

Comment: Is it possible to derive a WebPart from the List View Web Part and then just change the filtering?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be possible to Access any internal CAML inside the List Viewer webpart and modify it directly? This would be a hack.